# cannot be tracked because another instance.. AsNoTracking set tho

Tags: c#, sql, oop, entity-framework-core, orm

after searching and experimenting  i still get the error cannot be tracked because another instance even when i have disabled the tracking.....

this is my code

```
    var result = _customerContext.Set<DO_Customer>()
              .AsNoTracking()
              .Where(x => x.Id == toUpdate.Id).FirstOrDefault();



                if (result != null)
                {
                    _customerContext.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate);
                    _customerContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    foreach (var item in toUpdate.Address)
                    {
                        _customerContext.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(toUpdate);

                        _customerContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    }
}

            await _customerContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Anyone know why AsNoTracking is not  working?

i have try everything.
Only when i  add no tracking in the program.cs it seem to work but thats other code and don't want to disable it fully